# how to create a linked-list in a hash-table with the specific index?

Tags: java, linked-list, hashtable, collision

```
public boolean isCollide(String key, String value){
    int index = key.hashCode();
    if (this.key_array[index]==null) return false;
    else return true;
}
public void addValue(String key, String value){
      Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable(key,value);
      int index = key.hashCode();
      if (isCollide(key,value)) {
          hashtable.key_array[index]=key;
          hashtable.value_array[index]=value;
      }
      else{
          LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
          linkedList.add(value); //how to create a linkedlist on a hashtable?
      }
}
```

I'm implementing Hashtable from scratch. I was wondering how to create a linked-list in a hashtable? The code above is pretty much wrong but I hope it could illustrate what I'm thinking. So if there is a collision, then I would like to create a linked list starting from that collided index. Could anyone give me some guidance pls? Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us why? The Java HashMap does that internally (with a tree) for you. If you want to really put Lists into a existing hashmap, you need to declare it as `HashMap<List<String>>` or if you want to add both then `HashMap<Object>` (as `String` and `List` have no other common interface).

Comment: @eckes Sorry I should have stated it ahead: I'm implementing a hashtable from scratch without using Hashtable, Hashmap... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how Java HashMap does it internally:

```
class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> next;
    int hash;

    /**
     * Creates new entry.
     */
    Entry(int h, K k, V v, Entry<K,V> n) {
        value = v;
        next = n;
        key = k;
        hash = h;
    }

    // rest of methods here...
}
```

Entry class maintains internal "next" property for building linked list of colliding keys.

Basically key and value pair is stored internally as an instance of the Entry class. If collision happens, new Entry instance is being added as a next node to the last item in the slot. pseudo code:

```
table[i].next = newEntry;
```

---